# change attribute to element by Tag name

Tags: javascript

I have an alement that I want to put a class to. But the loop keeps giving me

*getElementsByTagName is not defined*

```
<script>
var textarea = getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for(i = 0; i<textarea.length; i++){
textarea .setAttribute("class" "textbox")
}
</script>

 <textarea></textarea>
 <textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` is not located in the global / `window` object, but in `document` for instance.

```
document.getElementsByTagName();
```

You need to explicitly call it like above, or on any `Node` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
textarea[i].className="textbox";
//       ^     ^
//       |     |
//   index     |
//         className is the property to change
```

Comment: of course the index. but the other thing is that the textbox don't have a class yet, shouldn't be setAttribute then ?

Comment: @Dymond no : doing className="something" sets the class even if there is none yet.